# Troubleshooting Dependency Injection Error in .NET 5 API Background Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-5

The primary goal is to reload user account data at regular 30-minute intervals within a .NET 5 API. In pursuit of this goal, I learned something about implementing background tasks to automate this process. Following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IekoUio2Fek), I attempted to set up a background task, also having a `scopedService`. However, during the implementation, I encountered persistent errors:

1.

> “No service for type ‘AccountRepository.AccountScopedService’ has been registered.”

Despite multiple troubleshooting attempts, including service registration checks, dependency injection verification, and rewatching the video, the error remains unresolved.

2. If I undo the last step of the video and just use `IAccountSingletonService singletonService,                    IAccountTransientService transientService` in the ctor (that is, without `IServiceProvider serviceProvider`), the application freezes. Swagger is not loaded.
   [image: busy]

I appreciate your help.

**AccountLoaderBackgroundService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AccountRepository
{
    public class AccountLoaderBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        public readonly List<Person> AllPersons = new List<Person>();
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly IAccountSingletonService singletonService;
        private readonly IAcountTransientService transientService;

        public AccountLoaderBackgroundService(IAccountSingletonService singletonService,
                                              IAcountTransientService transientService,
                                              IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AccountScopedService>();
                    LoadAccounts();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteAsync in AccountLoaderBackgroundService");
                    await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
                }
            }
        }

        public bool LoadAccounts()
        {
            // reading data
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountLoaderHostedService.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AccountRepository
{
    public class AccountLoaderHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("StartAsync in AccountLoaderHostedService");
                await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSingleton<AccountRepository.IAccountSingletonService, AccountRepository.AccountSingletonService>();
services.AddScoped<AccountRepository.IAccountScopedService, AccountRepository.AccountScopedService>();
services.AddTransient<AccountRepository.IAcountTransientService, AccountRepository.AcountTransientService>();
services.AddHostedService<AccountRepository.AccountLoaderBackgroundService>();
services.AddHostedService<AccountRepository.AccountLoaderHostedService>();
```

Plus, I wrote the classes and interfaces for the 3 services.

```
public class AccountScopedService : IAccountScopedService
    {
    }

public class AccountSingletonService : IAccountSingletonService
    {
    }

public class AcountTransientService : IAcountTransientService
    {
    }

public interface IAccountScopedService
    {
    }

public interface IAccountSingletonService
    {
    }

public interface IAcountTransientService
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're registering the interface `IAccountScopedService` in `startup.cs` on line 2, but you're requesting the concrete class `AccountScopedService` in `AccountLoaderBackgroundService.cs` on line 30. To fix this, you should request `IAccountScopedService` instead of `AccountScopedService` on line 30 in `AccountLoaderBackgroundService.cs`.

Hope it helps. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to contact me.

Kind regards
Nico

Comment: Thank you, that solves the first problem. The only question left is why the API takes a long time to start. I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Found out, in `AccountLoaderHostedService`, I have to return early, when starting (not `await Task.Delay`). I use a ulong counter, and if it's 0ul, I return early.